# GWT get build date

Tags: gwt, date, compiler-construction

When I compile my webapplication in GWT I would like the compile to set a date/time or update a buildnumber in my application but I just can't figure out how.
Is there a way to run code on compilation?
Or is it possible to let my compiler fill this in at the right spot (through the project.xml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either modify your source code before calling the GWT compiler (relatively easy with Maven and resource filtering, or with Ant, and probably any kind of build script), or possibly write a GWT generator for that.

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#generators

Comment: This is ofcourse the perfect solution I was looking for. I'm looking into generators some more.

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the document last modified date, which should be the build date:

```
public static native String getDocumentLastModifiedDate() 
/*-{ 
      return document.lastModified; 
}-*/;
```

Comment: Well, not totaly true. If I upload the project to another server that will set the last modified date to that moment. Working with generators can give me even more info. Like who compilled it etc.